# Are the neural network activation functions implemented correctly?

Tags: python, math, machine-learning, neural-network, activation

I've implemented a bunch of activation functions for neural networks, and I just want have validation that they work correctly. I implemented sigmoid, tanh, relu, arctan, step function, squash, and gaussian and I use their implicit derivative (in terms of the output) for backpropagation.

```
import numpy as np

def sigmoid(x, derivative=False):
    if (derivative == True):
        return x * (1 - x)
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))

def tanh(x, derivative=False):
    if (derivative == True):
        return (1 - (x ** 2))
    return np.tanh(x)

def relu(x, derivative=False):
    if (derivative == True):
        for i in range(0, len(x)):
            for k in range(len(x[i])):
                if x[i][k] > 0:
                    x[i][k] = 1
                else:
                    x[i][k] = 0
        return x
    for i in range(0, len(x)):
        for k in range(0, len(x[i])):
            if x[i][k] > 0:
                pass  # do nothing since it would be effectively replacing x with x
            else:
                x[i][k] = 0
    return x

def arctan(x, derivative=False):
    if(derivative == True):
        return (np.cos(x) ** 2)
    return np.arctan(x)

def step(x, derivative=False):
    if(derivative == True):
        for i in range(0, len(x)):
            for k in range(len(x[i])):
                if x[i][k] > 0:
                    x[i][k] = 0
        return x
    for i in range(0, len(x)):
        for k in range(0, len(x[i])):
            if x[i][k] > 0:
                x[i][k] = 1
            else:
                x[i][k] = 0
    return x

def squash(x, derivative=False):
    if(derivative == True):
        for i in range(0, len(x)):
            for k in range(0, len(x[i])):
                if x[i][k] > 0:
                    x[i][k] = (x[i][k])/(1+x[i][k])
                else:
                    x[i][k] = (x[i][k]) / (1 - x[i][k])
        return x
    for i in range(0, len(x)):
        for k in range(0, len(x[i])):
            x[i][k] = (x[i][k]) / (1 + abs(x[i][k]))
    return x

def gaussian(x, derivative=False):
    if (derivative == True):
        for i in range(0, len(x)):
            for k in range(0, len(x[i])):
                x[i][k] = -2* x[i][k] * np.exp(-x[i][k] ** 2)
    for i in range(0, len(x)):
        for k in range(0, len(x[i])):
            x[i][k] = np.exp(-x[i][k] ** 2)
    return x
```

The input x is the result of the output matrix of the previous layer multiplied by the weight matrix. The output x is the resultant of the activation function on the matrix to be used for the next layer.

Did I implement them in the way that it was intended to be used, or do some of these not give the intended results?

Comment: You probably want to ask this in [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) instead of Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thank you so much, I did not know that it existed!

Comment: I'm not sure if your derivatives are correct. Could just be that I'm not understanding how you intend to use these functions. Sigmoid should be ```(sigmoid(x) * (1 - sigmoid(x))``` not ```x * (1 - x)```, for instance.

Comment: Each time that the derivative part of the function is being called, the input that is used as x is already the output of the function, therefore x * (1-x) make sense since x is already the output of the sigmoid function, but this should hold true for any of the derivatives that is in the code above, not just sigmoid.

Comment: I see. That was not made clear in your code excerpt. In this case, does that mean that the derivative for your step function is always 0? That seems problematic for a traditional neural network. Traditionally the step activation is used only with specialized networks, as the derivative is not defined.